# Entity Framework 6 on .NET Core 2.2 - one to many return empty list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I spend all day to repair this bug but nothing happened. I use Entity Framework 6 with .NET Core 2.2.

I have `Driver` class which have list of many `DailyRoute`:

```
public class Driver
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DriverId { get; protected set; }
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; protected set; }

    private ISet<DailyRoute> _dailyRoutes = new HashSet<DailyRoute>();

    public virtual ICollection<DailyRoute> DailyRoutes
    {
        get => _dailyRoutes;

        set => _dailyRoutes = new HashSet<DailyRoute>(value);
    }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; private set; }

    protected Driver() 
    {
    }

    public Driver (Guid userid)
    {
        DriverId = userid;
    }
}
```

This is the `DailyRoute` class:

```
public class DailyRoute
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; protected set; }

    private ISet<PassengerNode> _passengerNodes = new HashSet<PassengerNode>();

    public Route Route { get; protected set; }

    public Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PassengerNode> PassengerNodes => _passengerNodes;

    public DailyRoute()
    {
    }

    protected DailyRoute(DateTime dateTime, Route route, Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Route = route;
        DateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

The problem is I debug program and when I update user and then show the actual `dbcontext` element there was driver with the dailyRoute list but and on the next request when I try to show all drivers, I got the driver with empty daily route list. In the database, I have a table with dailyRoute with driver Id and this Id does exist in the `Driver` table.

The `dbContext` class:

```
public class PassengerContext : DbContext
{
    public PassengerContext(DbContextOptions<PassengerContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DailyRoute> DailyRoutes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>()
            .HasMany(e => e.DailyRoutes).WithOne(k => k.Driver).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

This is the class when i try to get Driver, the driver exist but the dailyRoute list is empty;

```
public class DriverRepository : IDriverRepository
{
    private readonly PassengerContext _passengerContext;

    public DriverRepository(PassengerContext passengerContext)
    {
        _passengerContext = passengerContext;
    }

    public async Task<Driver> GetAsync(Guid userId)
    {
        return await _passengerContext.Drivers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.DriverId == userId);
    }
```

`Driver` table:

[image: The driver table]

`DailyRoute` table:

[image: DailyRoute table]

Comment: I believe that you have three entities Driver, Route and DailyRoute. DailyRoute is for mapping many to many relationship between Driver and Route entities. Look at this example for configuration https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Comment: Yes i have driver which have many DailyRoute and DailyRoute have only one Route

Comment: To get this result is required to configured with the Fluent API or entity framework doing this automatically ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: I use this https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration to return driver with dailyRoute list but list is also empty

Comment: In my opinion, your case is many to many relationship between Driver and Route entities. DailyRoute entity is for mapping Driver to Route on a specific date

Comment: When i try to use one to many i cant get this result ? I dont know why i get the empty daily route but on database table the driverId is on dailyRoute table in column DriverId. The entity framework dont mapping this automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

There are different loading policies in entity framework such as "eager loading" and "lazy loading". By default it would be lazy loading.

If you want the associated entities to loaded, then you have to make it eager loading. you can do this by adding a Include function in your linq query. The [Link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx) could probably help you.

The below change should probably fix the issue for you. Not compiled, so minor compilations issues possible

```
 return await _passengerContext.Drivers.Include(x => x.DailyRoutes).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.DriverId == userId);
```

Comment: But i want to get all users i dont what to pass the userId

Comment: was just modifying your code "public async Task<Driver> GetAsync(Guid userId)". If you need to get all, then don't filter on userid

Comment: In this case, he doesn't even get an empty list. When i debug _passengerContext and show driver a i have DailyRoute list but is empty. When i add dailyRoute to driver and debug databaseContext driver have list with dailyRoute but when i try to get all driver this list on all users was empty